# Where can I found definition for selectableItemBackgroundBorderless reference attribute?

Tags: android, attributes, android-appcompat, android-theme

Where I can found definition for ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless  ?

For example:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/removeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
```

I mean I can see reference definition in appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml
i.e.:

```
<item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
```

But where is defined this attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my installation, I'm using:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

I found selectableItemBackgroundBorderless defined in \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res\values\themes_material.xml
where:

```
<item name="selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@drawable/item_background_borderless_material</item>
```

then in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res\drawable\item_background_borderless_material.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />
```

and colorControlHighlight defined in Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res\values\themes_material.xml as:

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_light</item>
```

@color/ripple_material_light defined in Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\data\res\color\ripple_material_light.xml as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="@dimen/highlight_alpha_material_light"
          android:color="@color/foreground_material_light" />
</selector>
```

What an absurd ride...